# Do Aiuas in Enderverse have gender?

Tags: enders-game

Looking at this SFF question: [Jane's gender in Ender's Game series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/janes-gender-in-enders-game-series) , the two answers seem to give contradictory statements:

> they pulled a lady-aiua, as that's what all the Hive Queens are.

and

> Aiuas also have no inherent sex, just a desire to hold the pattern.

Can someone prove with canon quotes which one it is?

**Are there "Lady" Aiuas, or are they genderless?**

Comment: I'm working up an answer but as I have only the kindle versions to work from, it's slow going... but soon!

Comment: @sarge_smith - This answer is going to be awesome...

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. They do NOT have gender, at least Jane considers that (s)he does not. She tells Miro in *Children of the Mind*:

> “I’m not as set on using Val’s body as you were to have me do it,” said Jane. “Peter’s will do as well. Even Ender’s, as long as he’s not using it. **I’m not actually female. That was merely my choice of identity to get close to Ender**. He had problems bonding readily with men. The dilemma I have is that even if Ender would let go of one of these bodies for me to use it, I don’t know how to get there. I don’t know where my aiua is any more than you do. Can you put your aiua where you want it? Where is it now?”